# What does FUN mean in deriv() within R?

Tags: r

First, I am pertty pertty green.
Recently, I was using the deriv() or deriv3() to do homeworks. But I just couldn't understand what the help(deriv) page says. For example:

```
dx2x <- deriv(~ x^2, "x") ; dx2x
## function returned:
deriv((y ~ sin(cos(x) * y)), c("x","y"), func = TRUE)

## function with defaulted arguments:
(fx <- deriv(y ~ b0 + b1 * 2^(-x/th), c("b0", "b1", "th"),
             function(b0, b1, th, x = 1:7){} ) )
fx(2, 3, 4)
```

Sometimes, the FUN won't appear, and sometimes TRUE value or empty function body are applied to it. So, what is the differences among these three?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your confusion is whether a function is returned  , when `func=TRUE`, or what `R` calls an `expression`.  If you type

```
eval(dx2x)
```

You'll get the full calculation output for that `expression` .  --- well, you will if you have an object `x` in your environment :-)